# Onde aplicar a função sleep() em python para limitar requisições

Tags: python, for

O endpoint onde consulto as informações que eu quero possui uma limitação de requisição, precisa esperar 30s pra fazer 10 requisições.
Queria usar a função 'sleep()' mas não sei onde colocar.

```
import requests

aprovados = []

for id_vaga in lista_id:

  url = "https://teste.teste/teste"

  headers = {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": bearer
  }

  response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  aprovados.append(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa usar o sleep logo antes de fazer a requisição, a cada 10 requisições. Pra isso você precisa saber quantas requisições já foram realizadas. A solução seria:

```
import requests
import time

aprovados = []
total_requests = 0

for id_vaga in lista_id:
  
  total_requests++
  url = "https://teste.teste/teste"
  headers = {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": bearer
  }
  if (total_requests % 10 == 0)
    time.sleep(30)


  response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  aprovados.append(response.text)
```

assim, a cada dezena de requests, haverá um delay de 30 segundos para a próxima.